# MongoDB ObjectId usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I'm using **MongoDB** with **Mongoose ODM** for my **NodeJS REST** project:

my model **schema** is:

```
var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    team: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
})
```

and **server side**:

```
app.post('/players', function(req, res) {
  Players.find(function(err, players) {
    res.json(players);
  });
});
```

the **response** is:

```
...
{
  "_id": "511a6010e6ca7b0fe0af02ff",
  "name": "player-1",
  "team": "511a53e2e6ca7b151c09ce8d"
}
...
```

but I want something like:

```
{
  "_id": "511a6010e6ca7b0fe0af02ff",
  "name": "player-1",
  "team": {
    _id: "511a53e2e6ca7b151c09ce8d"
    name: "team-1"
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? 
or I haven't really understood the ObjectId?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to check out .populate   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Yeah thanks I had lost this step!

Answer (score 1):

You are only fetching the players document which have id of team document.

So for each player you have to get team doc also.

```
Players.find(function(err, players) {
   for(var i in players){
      Team.findById(players[i].team,function(error,teams){
          players[i].team = teams;
      })
   }
    res.json(players);
});
```